# How to observe a collection of items for when they are all valid?

Tags: system.reactive, reactiveui

I'm using ReactiveUI and the provided `ReactiveCollection<>` class.

In a ViewModel I have a collection of objects, and I wish to create an observable that watches those items for their IsValid property.

This is the scenario I'm trying to solve. In my ViewModel's constructor.

```
this.Items = new ReactiveCollection<object>();

IObservable<bool> someObservable = // ... how do I watch Items so when 
                                   // any items IsValid property changes, 
                                   // this observable changes. There
                                   // is an IValidItem interface.

this.TheCommand = new ReactiveCommand(someObservable);

...

interface IValidItem { bool IsValid { get; } }
```

**EDIT** Ana's answer got me most of the way there. The solution is the following.

```
this.Items = new ReactiveCollection<object>();
this.Items.ChangeTrackingEnabled = true;

var someObservable = this.Items.Changed
    .Select(_ => this.Items.All(i => i.IsValid));
```

Comment: Is there no way to avoid leaving the monad when using the `Changed` observable? I've got this same kind of thing in my own code, but it feels kinda clumsy to have to ignore the values in the sequence and step back out to get the full property value (`this.Items` here). :/

Comment: @MalRoss Not sure what the changed observable gives you. If it gives you a snapshot of the collection at the time of changed then it would be possible to stay in the monad, but I suspect ReactiveCollection is being lazy and just returning the changed object at best.

Answer (score 5):

It depends on what you want to *do* with the results of IsValid. Here's how I would do it, though it's not entirely intuitive:

```
// Create a derived collection which are all the IsValid properties. We don't
// really care which ones are valid, rather that they're *all* valid
var isValidList = allOfTheItems.CreateDerivedCollection(x => x.IsValid);

// Whenever the collection changes in any way, check the array to see if all of
// the items are valid. We could probably do this more efficiently but it gets
// Tricky™
IObservable<bool> areAllItemsValid = isValidList.Changed.Select(_ => isValidList.All());

theCommand = new ReactiveCommand(areAllItemsValid);
```

Comment: So what is isValidList used for? Was the second part supposed to be isValidList.Changed.Selected(... instead of allOfTheItems?

Comment: hwhoops, coding via text area. Fixed!

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using ReactiveUI, you have a few options. If your objects are `ReactiveValidatedObject`s you can actually use the ValidationObservable:

```
var someObservable = this.Items
    .Select(o => o.ValidationObservable
        .Select(chg => chg.GetValue()) //grab just the current bool from the change
        .StartsWith(o.IsValid)) //prime all observables with current value
    .CombineLatest(values => values.All());
```

If they aren't ReactiveValidatedObjects, but implement INotifyPropertyChanged, you would just replace the first line and use the handy ObservableForProperty extension method in ReactiveUI for those objects. Instead of `o.ValidationObservable` you would use `o.ObservableForProperty(x => x.IsValid)`. The rest should be the same.

This is a pretty common use case and I've wrapped it in an extension method for `IEnumerable<ReactiveValidatedObject>`

I'm sure Paul Betts will come along with something more elegant, but this is what I do.